# Word for eerily quiet manner when plotting something/scheming

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I remember seeing a word that defined someone's creepy manner or eery quietness when having plotted against or going to plot against someone/thing. If not that, just the quietness associated with psychopathic tendencies (think of a creepy kid in class that's smiling to himself after the class discovery of his murdering of the pet guinea pig.)

Answer (score 1):

I would say your boy is either [insidious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insidious):

> operating or proceeding in an inconspicuous or seemingly harmless way but actually with grave effect

or [uncanny](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uncanny):

> mysterious; arousing superstitious fear or dread; uncomfortably strange

Answer (score 0):

Smirk . Reference - [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/smirk)

Answer (score 0):

*Discreet* . Doing something in a manner that won't attract attention

Answer (score 0):

**Sardonic** may fit.

> Definition: characterized by bitter or scornful derision; mocking;
>   cynical; disdainful; sneering.

Example: *a sardonic grin*.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I don't see that *sardonic* has anything to do with this question.